# Unclear of Meaning of Notation $\cap _{n=1}^\infty (0,1/n)=\varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I am a bit unclear about the notation involved in the following question of my textbook. I am concerned with understanding what is asked by the question - please do not give the answer.

$\textbf{1.4.3.}$ Prove: $\bigcap \limits _{n=1}^\infty \left (0,\dfrac{1}{n}\right )=\varnothing$.

(From Stephen Abbot's "Understanding Analysis").

What exactly is meant by $\left (0,\dfrac{1}{n}\right )$? Is this simply the tuple containing $0$ and $\dfrac{1}{n}$? If this is the case then I think my proof would simply entail proving $\dfrac{1}{n_1}\neq \dfrac{1}{n_2}$ for $n_1\neq n_2$, which seems like a trivial result (hence why I ask my question - this feels too simple to be what the question is really asking).

Comment: The open interval $(0,\frac{1}{n})$, $\{x: 0<x<\frac{1}{n} \} $

Comment: It is quite annoying that most sources use the same notation $(a,b)$ for a point with coordinates $x=a, y=b$, and for the open interval $\{x \in \mathbb R: a < x < b \}$.

Comment: Not terribly important in light of the actual answer, but **if** we interpreted $(0,1/n)$ as a point, then since the intersection acts on sets, we'd have to use one of the methods to encode a pair as a set, e.g. as $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.  This would lead to the awkward $\bigcap_n (0,1/n) = \{\{0\}\} \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @Trivial When editing title we try to make it takes as little vertical space as possible (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-mathjax-in-question-titles))

Comment: ... and Abbot never mentioned the open interval notation $(a,b)$ before 1.4.3 ?

Comment: @Artic Char Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't know that. I'll take it in consideration from now on.

Comment: @GEdgar you are correct he does mention this notation on page 16 - it was a comprehension error on my part not so much a problem with the textbook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, this means the open interval $(0,1/n)$. In general, for $a<b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$(a,b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x < b \}$$

For instance, $(0,1)$ contains all numbers between $0$ and $1$ (but not including $0$ and $1$ themselves). There are analogous notions for half-open and closed intervals:

$$\begin{align*}
(a,b] &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < x \le b \} \\
[a,b) &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a \le x < b \} \\
[a,b] &:= \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a \le x \le b \} \\
\end{align*}$$

(As a final addendum, some write $]a,b[$ to mean $(a,b)$.)